# how to avoid the pointer, pointing after the '\0'?

Tags: c++, function, recursion

the idea of this function is to swap the letters of a word. It works with an even amount of letters, but when it's odd, it doesn't. I know that mix(a+2) gives us a value which is after the '\0' and that's why it prints some random number after the output. How can i modify my if-statement so i can avoid this problem? Sorry for the stupid question, but i'm still new to programming.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void mix(char* a) {
    if (*(a+1)) {
        char temp = *a;
        *a=*(a+1);
        *(a+1)=temp;

        mix(a+2);
    }
}

int main() {
    char a[] = "angela";
    mix(a);
    cout << a;
}
```

Comment: Why not check `*a` for not being `'\0'`?

Comment: tried, but then it doesn't printout the last letter

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: i only did -" if (*a!='\0')"  and removed the "*(a+1)". That's why i got the missing letter with odd numbers.

Comment: Use `std::string`?  Character arrays have issues, as you have found out.

Comment: If you're new to programming, don't use `char*` or arrays :-) Use `std::string` and `std::vector`. You should also avoid using them if you're not new to programming. They should only be used when you have no other option.

Comment: The strange thing is that we haven't learned vectors and std::string. I don't know why, but we aren't allowed to use them in our assignments as well.

Answer (score 3):

Do make sure that `*a` is also not `'\0'`.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void mix(char* a){

    if (*a && *(a+1)) {
        char temp = *a;
        *a=*(a+1);
        *(a+1)=temp;

        mix(a+2);
    }
}

int main()
{
    char a[] = "angela";
    mix(a);
    cout << a;

    return 0;
}
```